# Can someone please tell me what kind of bike this is please?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I'm not sure what kind of bike this is. It was given to me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to take a look at "[How do I ask a good “ID My Bike” question?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question)"

Comment: It's certainly an unusual-looking frame from February 2001.  This is not a BSO, and is worth persevering.  Can you please provide some better photos ?   HAEM's link has some excellent pointers.

Comment: Unusual is an understatement... Definitely looks entirely handmade.

Comment: @DavidW Never seen a hand-made frame with an ID sticker like that....  More likely the welding is just how it was done.  A quick search shows nothing, but I can't come up with a good keyword for "filled-in frame"

Comment: @chuck can you identify the frame and both fork materials?  A magnet will show if its Steel.  Closeup photos of labels will help too.

Comment: @Criggie I can't imagine how heavy the bike would be if that's all steel! :)

Comment: @DavidW excellent point - I see a dual-crown fork on the left of the image, so with lots of added weight could have been some kind of downhill bike, where the weight is an advantage.  Total speculation though, so comment not answer.

Comment: The raised chain stay with no seat stay should help identify it.  It was an era where Full Sus geometries were still under patent protection and manufacturers needed to be creative to avoid paying licensing fees (or worse, getting sued).  Can we see a picture of the full bike(right side up).

Comment: Why would it not be BSO? Square taper cranks in 2001, stamped sheet metal chainrings, the seat post clamp and huge coil spring point to that direction. Better photos would still help.

Comment: BB were another area of patent wars in 2001.  Square Taper means nothing from that era except it was not High end $himano.

Comment: Ah yes, 2001 was slightly before ISIS Drive and far before that organization with similar name.

Answer (score 1):

The date sticker is standard on boxmart junk bikes, aka bso.  They have to recall so many they include the exact date of manufacture so they can just recall certain days of production instead of all of a particular model.

Answer (score 0):

It is a full-suspension MTB. Judging by the bare-metal swingarm, the previous owner probably took a decade-old frame for a project bicycle. It's fairly safe to presume everything attached to the frame is after-market and possibly custom-made.

Comment: bare metal swing arms were very common back then. I doubt any of it is custom. Looks like a low-end full suspension bike of that era. Possibly a bit nicer than low-end, but not a high priced offering. By 2001, those would have discs. Need a fuller image to get more info on manufacturer.

Comment: I know the forks that's on it don't go to it but  let me know what pics you want and I'll do it and is their any way to tell what it is by the VIN numbers

Comment: @Chuck your use of the term “VIN number” is telling. Unlike cars, there is no centralized database of serial numbers for bikes. Each manufacturer maintains their own set of numbers. They often don’t make the formatting public, or offer a way to search. Too many people seem to think that if they just give a screenshot of the serial numbers, we will somehow be able to access a magic database and find the bike. This is not so.